# SwiftUI - How to partially mask/clip an image?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, mask

I want to my image object to be become partially masked when moving (via animation) across a border. For reference, I want to make something like this:

| Position 1 | Position 2 | Position 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Red circle fully visible] | [image: Red circle half cut off by right border] | [image: Red circle almost completely cut off by right border] |

Hiding the image behind another image (and create a clipped illusion) will not work because my background may be dynamic. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> create a clipped illusion) will not work

Check out the [`.clipped()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/clipped(antialiased:)) modifier. It's the real thing, not an illusion.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset = CGFloat(0)
    
    var body: some View {    
        Group {
            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .offset(x: offset, y: 0)
        }
        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
        .border(Color.green) /// just for clarity, you can remove this
        .clipped() /// use this to prevent circle from going past borders
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 5)) {
                offset = 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Circle moving right and past the border, but as soon as it gets to the border it starts clipping]